# Source Control con 5.000 cosas que no me deja quitar y que no sé de dónde vienen. (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio, git, terminal

No sé que he hice mientras programaba o estaba por mi ordenador que de un momento para otro me sale lo de las imágenes, se ve que hice un repositorio sin querer en una carpeta donde no debía o algo, pero es que ni siquiera sé que archivos son porque busco en las carpetas y no me sale nada, como si directamente no existieran esos archivos, parece que es un problema de git o no lo sé.

He probado muchas cosas y no consigo solucionarlo, es que parece que ni puedo abrir el terminal, si le doy a Discard All Changes, me sale lo siguiente "Git: warning: failed to remove AppData/Local/Discord/app-0-0-307/resources/app.asar: Invalid argument". ¿Qué pinta el problema en una carpeta como Discord que ni siquiera me sale?

¿alguna idea o solución que me pueda servir?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: No me deja ni abrir terminal]
[image: Lo que me sale en Source Control]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al archivo `.gitignore` agrega `node_modules/`

Ese archivo está en la raíz de tu proyecto. Y si no está, a crearlo.

Si te genera mucho problema el tema, crea el proyecto en otra carpeta, de preferencia con menos nivel de jerarquía de carpetas como en `C:\Dev`. Saludos.